# find_element_by_link_text should find this link?

Tags: python, selenium

Quick question.

I have this code:

```
    albums_links = self.browser.\
        find_elements_by_link_text('Albums')
    # albums_links = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath(
    #    '//a[contains(@href, "albums")]') # this works (enough), I leave here for reference
    self.assertEqual(albums_links[0].get_attribute('href'),
        self.live_server_url + '/admin/albums/')
    self.assertEqual(albums_links[1].get_attribute('href'),
        self.live_server_url + '/admin/albums/album/')
```

It was working. Now I have reinstalled OS, redone the venv etc and the code isn't working anymore. In theory the only things different is the python version and the django version but I'm not sure because the changes are big.

So, I ask if that code should find both those links or only one:

```
<caption>
    <a href="/admin/albums/" class="section" title="Models in the Albums application">Albums</a>
 </caption>
     <tr class="model-album">
         <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/albums/album/">Albums</a></th>
```

Before (python 3.4 django 1.8) it found both, now (python 3.7.4, django 2.0) only the second one.
This behavior is consistent and work in the same way for other links in some "frame" like `Albums` or `Solos` and then in `Add Track` (is a standard django admin)

[image]

I'd see that In selenium the comand `find_element_by_link_text` isn't reliable but is this a feature?

Thank you

Edit: in other words maybe the class and the title inside the  elements can be a problem?

`Html` for "Add track":

```
<li>
   <a href="/admin/albums/track/add/" class="addlink">
     Add track
   </a>
</li>
```

Edit2: also the django version is different. Maybe something changed in the html?

Comment: can you show the difference between the old django  and the new one? (the HTML)

Comment: It isn't be easy to check but it looks the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using find_element_by_link_text, you could try XPath instead.

`driver.findElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(), 'Add track')]"));`

This is less complicated than find_element_by_link_text, and it will not break if the link changes, since we are only looking at the plain text inside the tag.

Hope this helps.